# How do I unlock the final galaxy in Super Mario Galaxy 2's world S?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy-2

I've finished Super Mario Galaxy 2.  At least, I though I had.  It appears there is a mysterious, unnamed final galaxy in world S.  **How do I unlock and get to this galaxy?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The absolutely last galaxy in *World S* is the **Grandmaster Galaxy**.

You have to collect all 120 Power Stars *and* 120 Green Stars to unlock it.

Comment: Holy cow. Seriously?

Comment: Yes, it really is the last level of the game and needs *everything* else done before you get to it. [Here](http://www.mariowiki.com/World_S_%28Super_Mario_Galaxy_2%29)'s a random wiki I've turned up on a quick search that should help confirm what I've said (just don't scroll down or click thru too much if you don't want spoilers)